# ¿Cómo mostrar el nombre del usuario que hizo los cambios en una tabla en una bitácora?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Estoy realizando un sistema en php donde necesito hacer una auditoría del sistema. Estoy usando los trigger de MYSQL.

Tengo una tabla `Personas` donde están sus datos y en una tabla llamada `bitacoraPersonas` muestro todos los cambios que se han hecho en esa tabla (insertar, eliminar, modificar).

Tengo una columna en la tabla de `BitacoraPersona` donde tengo `Usuario` y lo estoy llamando en el trigger como `USER()` que me muestra `rootlocalhost`.

Anexo uno de los trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Personas_AInsertar AFTER INSERT
ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora(idUsuario,Accion,fecha,cedula,nombreNuevo,apellidoNuevo,sexoNuevo,telefonoNuevo,direccionNuevo,fnacimientoNuevo) 
VALUES (USER(),'Inserto',NOW(),NEW.cedula,NEW.nombres,NEW.apellidos,NEW.sexo,NEW.telefono, NEW.direccion,NEW.fnacimiento);
```

---

**Mi consulta es la siguiente:**

Tengo otra tabla usuarios (que son los usuarios del sistema). Lo que quiero es, que en vez que salga `rootlocalhost`, aparezca el `ID`, `DNI` que me indique el usuario que hizo la modificación.

---

Esquema de la tabla `bitacorapersonas`:

```
CREATE TABLE `bitacorapersonas` (
  `idBitacora` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `Accion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `idUsuario` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `cedulaVieja` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombreNuevo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreViejo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoNuevo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoViejo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sexoNuevo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sexoViejo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefonoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `telefonoViejo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `direccionNuevo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `direccionViejo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `fnacimientoNuevo` date NOT NULL,
  `fnacimientoViejo` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Esquema de la tabla `usuarios`:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_session` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activacion` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

Esquema de la tabla `personas`:

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` text NOT NULL,
  `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Lo que necesito es que **en la tabla de bitácora me aparezca el `Id` del usuario de la tabla `Usuarios`** para así saber qué usuario fue el que hizo que modificación.

me dijeron que usara una variable definida para que mysql me reconociera en la tabla bitacora quien es el usuario... lo estaba haciendo asi

```
$sql="SELECT @usuarios_cedula:= usuarios_cedula FROM bitacorapersonas ";
                        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $registro = registraPersonas($cedula, $nombres, $apellidos, $sexo, $fnacimiento, $telefono, $direccion);



                        $registro = registraUsuario($email, $usuario, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario,$cedula);
```

PERO EN LA BITACORA NO ME MUESTRA NADA tambien coloque

```
$sql="SELECT @usuarios_cedula:= usuarios_cedula ";
                            $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

pero el resultado sigue igual

Comment: Podrías poner ejemplos de contenido de la tabla BitacoraPersona y de la tabla Personas para poder tener una mejor idea de cómo ayudarte? Para mi gusto falta información.

Comment: @MarcPuig listo, coloque las tablas para ver si puedes ayudarme

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código PHP que has usado, lo revisaré y modificaré si es necesario en una edición de mi respuesta. No puedo agregar más comentados a mi respuesta desde el móvil.

Comment: ya lo modifique @OscarGarcia

Comment: No me queda claro qué quieres que contenga `@usuarios_cedula`. ¿No quieres registrar algún dato relacionado con el usuario logueado? ¿Por qué haces un `SELECT` de `bitacorapersonas`? Por cierto, si no usas un `WHERE` se hará la asignación por cada registro de la tabla, prevaleciendo el último que se obtuvo (la última asignación es la que persiste tras la consulta). Te recomiendo encarecidamente usar `SET`. Dime en qué variable de PHP guardas la información del usuario logueado que quieres usar o bien cómo obtenerla de la base de datos.

Comment: lo guardo en una variable que se llama $usuario_cedula=$_POST['usuario_cedula']; que es el dni del usuario esa cedula es la que necesito que me salga en la bitacora.. para saber quien fue que modifico.. como hago el SET en php? antes del registroPersonas que te mostre arriba?

Comment: Hecho. Al usar consultas preparadas creo que la única forma de asignar un valor de manera segura es usando `SELECT`.

Comment: pero ya lo hice como te mostre y no me salio nada en la tabla de bitacora o en el from tengo que colocar es la tabla usuario?

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia aun sigo intentando y no me resulta. No se si haz notado algo que este haciendo mal :/ 
Gracias por tu gran apoyo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63589/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-rodrigo2324). No sé si tienes reputación suficiente para escribir en el chat, pero si puedes usarlo es mejor para mantener una conversación más fluida y liberar los comentarios de ese intercambio de información.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El servidor MySQL no sabe nada acerca de los datos del usuario de tu aplicación, por lo que deberás "darle pistas" acerca de quién es haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, [variables de usuario](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html):

```
SET @id_dni = (lo que tú quieras)
```

O bien:

```
SELECT @id_dni := campo FROM tabla WHERE clave_primaria = (lo que sea)
```

En tu caso (obtenido de los comentarios) podrías usar consultas preparadas con `SELECT`:

```
/* Preparamos la consulta */
$sql = 'SELECT @identificador := ?';
$consulta = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
/* Asignamos al primer ? el valor (entero) de nuestra variable */
$consulta->bind_param('i', $usuario_cedula);
/* Ejecutamos la consulta */
$consulta->execute();
/* A partir de ahora @identificador en el lado del servidor MySQL
  contiene lo mismo que $usuario_cedula en el lado de PHP */
```

Una vez hecho eso (antes de hacer cualquier consulta `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc) estará disponible para ser usado dentro del iniciador:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Personas_AInsertar AFTER INSERT ON personas 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO bitacora (
  idUsuario,
  Accion,
  fecha,
  cedula,
  nombreNuevo,
  apellidoNuevo,
  sexoNuevo,
  telefonoNuevo,
  direccionNuevo,
  fnacimientoNuevo
) VALUES (
  @identificador,
  'Inserto',
  NOW(),
  NEW.cedula,
  NEW.nombres,
  NEW.apellidos,
  NEW.sexo,
  NEW.telefono,
  NEW.direccion,
  NEW.fnacimiento
);
```

Aquí tienes una demostración en línea del correcto funcionamiento, en el que he asignado el valor de `@id_dni` a partir del resultado de una consulta `SELECT` en vez de usar una asignación directa con `SET` (así tienes dos formas diferentes de hacerlo):

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjC9aVLqim8esGw4niuzeK/0

PD: He tenido que modificar ligeramente el esquema de tus tablas para poder poner en funcionamiento el código ya que en un `INSERT` no existen valores previos de los campos, por lo que el `INSERT` fallaba porque los campos no tienen valor por defecto.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta sobre tu respuesta, ¿sería interesante, ya que es un log, en vez de crear el trigger con `AFTER INSERT` hacerlo con `BEFORE INSERT`? (Por prevenir la pérdida de información en el log) ¿O el trigger se ejecuta siempre y este detalle es indiferente?

Comment: Imagínate que quieres controlar una validación del contenido (restricciones con otras tablas, formato del DNI, teléfono, nombre, etc) y que quieres tener la posibilidad de cancelar la inserción antes de que ésta se produzca: usamos `BEFORE`. Ten en cuenta que en `BEFORE` aún no se han poblado los valores por defecto, por ejemplo. Así que casi siempre es mejor usar las auditorías cuando se ha hecho la inserción efectiva.

Comment: ¿Pero en caso de fallo de la base de datos, podrías tener una acción sin registrar en el log utilizando el `AFTER` no? La duda que realmente tengo es si la ejecución del trigger está asegurada.

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es lo suficientemente sólida (y su respuesta podría ayudar a otros usuarios con la misma duda) para crear una nueva pregunta de la comunidad para poder responderte a ella con referencias y enlaces a la documentación, ejemplos prácticos, etc. Como respuesta rápida: en caso de restricción de clave primaria o única ni `AFTER` ni `BEFORE` se ejecutan, pero no entiendo exactamente si es lo que quieres saber con "fallo de base de datos".

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora abriré una pregunta.

Comment: OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tu respuesta, otra pregunta, si estoy usando un sistema en php como le indicaria  a la bitacora que el usuario que inicia sesion seria SELECT @id_dni := CONCAT(id, ' - ', dni) FROM usuarios WHERE id = usuarios.id ?? o se haria en el select de php?

Comment: Se haría una consulta SQL desde PHP montando la cadena necesaria, como si de cualquier otra consulta SQL se tratase. Algo como `SET @id_dni = ?` en PDO o mysqli.

Comment: aplique lo que me dices colocandolo antes del registro ( me imagino que es de la persona) lo hice en php asi --> $sql="SELECT @usuarios_cedula:= '$usuarios_cedula'";
     $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

     $registro = registraPersonas($cedula, $nombres, $apellidos, $sexo, $fnacimiento, $telefono, $direccion); pero cuando fui a ver la bitacora no me registro nada en la parte de idUsuario

Comment: ¿Usaste la misma variable de usuario en el iniciador? ¿Comprobaste que el resultado de la consulta fue bien? ¿Has probado a usar un `SET` en vez de un `SELECT`?

Comment: en la tabla de bitacora salio vacia, como seria el SET en php, porque probre haciendo $sql="SET@usuarios_cedula:= '$usuarios_cedula'"; $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); pero no me sale nada, si tienes algun ejemplo te lo agradeceria

Comment: solo me faltaba un --> ? al final del wehere <- la solucion final fue esta 

    **function identificador($cedulanueva){
    
       global $mysqli;
    
       $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT @identificador:= usuarios_cedula FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios_cedula=?");
       $sql->bind_param('s', $cedulanueva);
       $sql->execute();
       
      
      } **

**cedulanueva** es mi cedula de la session asi mysql sabra quien es..

Comment: No me queda claro. En el caso de tener varios usuarios del sistema,cómo tu código detecta qué usuario está actualizando la tabla?

Comment: Hola @Puntay , justo como se indica en el comentario anterior al tuyo. Como puedes ver en mi respuesta, lo primero que se hace tras establecer la conexión al servidor es establecer el valor de la variable global `@identificador` con la consulta `SELECT @identificador := ?`. Yo propuse hacerlo usando la variable `$usuario_cedula` desde PHP, pero Rodrigo prefería usar el campo `usuarios_cedula` usando una consulta a la tabla `usuarios` buscando al usuario en cuestión. Inicialmente sugerí el nombre `@id_dni`, pero en los comentarios él usó `@usuarios_cedula`, por lo que hay un poco de mezcla.