# ¿Como mostrar el nombre del usuario que hizo un cambio en alguna tabla?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Estoy creando una plataforma en la cual tiene varios CRUD,  tengo un modulo que se llama auditoria (consultar la base de datos lo que se inserto, elimino, actualizo etc), estoy es para auditar el sistema, ahora bien tengo un campo que se llama usuario donde debe colocar el nombre del usuario que estvo logueado y realizo cierto cambio.

Actualmente tengo estos Triggers

```
--Triggers insertar

DELIMITER %%
CREATE TRIGGER insertar AFTER INSERT on usuario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO auditoria_usuario(idUsu, TipoUsuario_nuevo, Password_nuevo, NombreUsuario_nuevo, NombreCompleto_nuevo, EmailUsuario_nuevo, TelefonoUsuario_nuevo, Usuario, Fecha, Hora, Condicion) 
VALUES(new.UsuarioID, new.TipoUsuario, new.Password, new.NombreUsuario, new.NombreCompleto, new.EmailUsuario, new.TelefonoUsuario, USER(), curdate(), curtime(), 'Usuario Registrado');
END %%
DELIMITER ;

--Triggers actualizar

DELIMITER %%
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar AFTER UPDATE on usuario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO auditoria_usuario(idUsu, TipoUsuario_nuevo, TipoUsuario_viejo, Password_nuevo, Password_viejo, NombreUsuario_nuevo, NombreUsuario_viejo, NombreCompleto_nuevo, NombreCompleto_viejo, EmailUsuario_nuevo, EmailUsuario_viejo, TelefonoUsuario_nuevo, TelefonoUsuario_viejo, Usuario, Fecha, Hora, Condicion) 
VALUES(old.UsuarioID, old.TipoUsuario, old.Password, old.NombreUsuario, old.NombreCompleto, old.EmailUsuario, old.TelefonoUsuario, USER(), curdate(), curtime(), 'Usuario Modificado');
END %%
DELIMITER ;

--Triggers eliminar

DELIMITER %%
CREATE TRIGGER eliminar AFTER DELETE on usuario
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO auditoria_usuario(idUsu, TipoUsuario_viejo, Password_viejo, NombreUsuario_viejo, NombreCompleto_viejo, EmailUsuario_viejo, TelefonoUsuario_viejo, Usuario, Fecha, Hora, Condicion) 
VALUES(old.UsuarioID, old.TipoUsuario, old.Password, old.NombreUsuario, old.NombreCompleto, old.EmailUsuario, old.TelefonoUsuario, USER(), curdate(), curtime(), 'Usuario Eliminado');
END %%
DELIMITER ;
```

Con USER() y CURRENT USER () lo que me muestra el usuario de la base de datos, en este caso root ya que es mi usuario.

Ejemplo de lo que necesito hacer:

Si PEDRO que es un usuario del sistema se loguea en el sistema y registra un producto, entonces  viene el usuario administrador quien es que puede ver la auditoria y consulta en la auditoria debe indicar que PEDRO inserto un producto.

Referencias:

https://www.webempresa.com/foro/joomla-25/conocer-los-usuarios-que-modifican-registros-en-una-tabla-de-mi-ddbb

[¿Cómo mostrar el nombre del usuario que hizo los cambios en una tabla en una bitácora?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93787/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-el-nombre-del-usuario-que-hizo-los-cambios-en-una-tabla-en-una-bit?rq=1)

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con ese código?

Comment: Qye me esta trayendo el usuario de la DB no el usuario logueado, sabes como hacerlo compañero?

Comment: Estoy realizando un sistema en php donde necesito hacer una auditoría del sistema. Estoy usando los trigger de MYSQL.

Tengo una tabla donde están los datos y en en otra tabla muestro todos los cambios que se han hecho en esa tabla (insertar, eliminar, modificar).

Tengo una columna en la tabla de donde tengo Usuario y lo estoy llamando en el trigger como USER() que me muestra rootlocalhost, pero lo que necesito es el nombre del usuario logueado que hizo el cambio.

Comment: Ahi deberias ver en el lenguaje que hace la llamada a la DB de tu aplicacion que te pase el usuario que tiene loggeado en el query o sentencia, la BD no creo que te permita hacer esto

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es hacer una captura del usuario desde tu aplicación y guardarlo en algún lugar en tu BD

Comment: Como puedo hacer esto algún ejemplo en PHP y MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
$cu = wp_get_current_user(); (esto es wordpress)
if (is_user_logged_in()){
        global $cu;
        $reg = "SELECT registro FROM wp_users where ID=".$cu->ID;
        $log = "insert into wp_bitacora_usuario (id_usuario,accion,created_at) values (".$cu->ID.",'Log in',now())";
```

puedes adaptar esto a como te parezca, en esencia esto es lo que debes de hacer.